# Mongoose ODM - failing to validate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to perform validation without saving. The API documentation shows that there's a [validate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here's my schema file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  mainHeading: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "This is the heading"
  }
});

var moduleheading = mongoose.model('moduleheading', schema);

module.exports = {
  moduleheading: moduleheading
}
```

..and then in my controller:

```
var moduleheading = require("../models/modules/heading").moduleheading; //load the heading module model

var ModuleHeadingo = new moduleheading({
    mainHeadin: true,
    conten: "This appears to have validated.."
});
ModuleHeadingo.validate(function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('module heading validation passed');
    }
});
```

You may notice that the parameters I'm passing in are called 'mainHeadin' and 'conten' instead of 'mainHeading' and 'content'. However, even when I do the call to validate() it never returns an error.

I'm obviously using validate incorrectly - any tips? The mongoose documentation is really lacking!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation will never fail because you've created default attributes for both `mainHeading` and `content` in your schema. In other words, if you don't set either of those properties, Mongoose will default them to `false` and `"This is the heading"` respectively - i.e. they will always be defined.

Once you remove the default property, you'll find that Document#validate will work as you initially expected. Try the following for your schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  mainHeading: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Spot on, seems really simple when you look at it that way!